# p:fileupload doesnt work on Websphere 8

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, websphere, primefaces, ibm-rad

I wonder if anyone managed to get Primefaces' `p:fileupload` component work on Websphere Application Server 8.

I use Primefaces 2.2.1 version.

*JSF code:*

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    <p:fileUpload 
            fileUploadListener="#{mailBean.handleFileUpload}"   
            multiple="true" 
            label="choose" 
            allowTypes="*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;" 
            description="Images"/>          
</h:form>
```

*Managed Bean code:*

```
public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) 
{  
    files.add(event.getFile());
    logger.info("File uploaded into MailBean: " + event.getFile());
    System.out.println("File uploaded into MailBean: " + event.getFile());
}
```

*Web.xml filter:* (Servlet 3.0)

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
        <param-value>51200</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
        <param-value>c:/temp/pf</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

The component says HTTP error and turns into red, on the console I get a ViewExpiredException by Myfaces:

```
Caused by: javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: /createmail.xhtml
           No saved view state could be found for the view identifier: /createmail.xhtml
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RestoreViewExecutor.execute(RestoreViewExecutor.java:128)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:171)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:189)
```

I even tried with two other versions of Mojarra instead of Myfaces, but I got errors (2.1: handler doesnt get invoked, 2.0.3: viewexpired)

Answer (score 0):

Did u have the .jars and the web.xml config (remove "c:", the default is that route) ? I had the same problem but then i restarted my WAS 8.5 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Websphere 7 with JSF 2.0 with Mojarra 2 and PrimeFaces 3.4.2 (common-fileupload-1.2.2.jar and common-io-1.3.2.jar)

I see the fileUpload don't call the bean in WebSphere.
I see the bar that load the file but don't arrive the event on the managedBean.

It seems as if some other filter in Websphere capture the HTTP request and you can't get data sent by fileUpload because are just consumed :(